# Как убрать отступ при наведение на элемент?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
.square {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    transition: border .2s linear;
}

.square:hover {
    border: 2px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
    Square
</div>
```

Comment: первое, что придумал, сделать в .square `border: 2px transparent solid`

Comment: Как вариант `box-sizing: border-box` в зависимости от желаемого поведения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какой именно отступ убрать нужно? Если нужно убрать смещение текста, то можно сделать так.

```css
.square {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  transition: border-color .2s linear;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.square:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  Square
</div>
```